# about pagination gmail api with php

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, gmail-api

I listed the messages in My App successfully. Now I need to paginate the messages 
(about 8 in every page). I followed the doc of google but it only gives a pageToken but how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you [list messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), and there still are more results to fetch, the response will contain a `nextPageToken`.

**Request**

```
userId = me
maxResults = 8

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=8&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "151596a5055b9412",
   "threadId": "151596a5055b9412"
  },
  {
   "id": "1515915d0fcfd685",
   "threadId": "1515915d0fcfd685"
  },
  {
   "id": "15158e6826ed7587",
   "threadId": "15158e6826ed7587"
  },
  {
   "id": "15158e0e37572671",
   "threadId": "15158e0e37572671"
  },
  {
   "id": "151586443b5b309a",
   "threadId": "151586443b5b309a"
  },
  {
   "id": "15157c4b11732c5c",
   "threadId": "1510f004b81a9de2"
  },
  {
   "id": "151576512d37c9ec",
   "threadId": "1515765122918d37"
  },
  {
   "id": "1515765122918d37",
   "threadId": "1515765122918d37"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "01770178536732383613", // Here it is!
 "resultSizeEstimate": 26
}
```

Just include this value as the `pageToken` in the next request.

**Request**

```
userId = me
maxResults = 8
pageToken = 01770178536732383613

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=8&pageToken=01770178536732383613&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "1515762549119366",
   "threadId": "1513f096ab90fdab"
  },
  {
   "id": "15157616d03a66a1",
   "threadId": "1513f096ab90fdab"
  },
  {
   "id": "151575f958ac69e8",
   "threadId": "1513338849950602"
  },
  {
   "id": "1515756737710843",
   "threadId": "1515756737710843"
  },
  {
   "id": "1515756735412b45",
   "threadId": "1515756735412b45"
  },
  {
   "id": "1515756710eed602",
   "threadId": "1515756710eed602"
  },
  {
   "id": "15157567089a24b0",
   "threadId": "15157567089a24b0"
  },
  {
   "id": "151574a87fefe71d",
   "threadId": "151336e890f46a2c"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "13534757816909071635",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 27
}
```

When there is no `nextPageToken` in the response you have fetched every result there is.

Comment: thank you I did everything as you said and then I got an error
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}

Comment: @khaleader You need a correct token. Try getting a token at the [Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) by using the Gmail API scopes and try again.

Comment: I appreciate your help , the link above takes me outside the app 
I want to stay inside the app and since i'm using laravel I think it's impossible to paginate without the built in paginator

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is storing in an array of the front all the tokens that it brings you to be able to go forward and backward between pages, being the index of the array the pages, if it does not bring you the nextPageToken it is because it is the last one, then you pass the current token (of the page where you are) as parameter, and it brings you the list of emails of that page.